# What is a good cross platform audio processing library?

Tags: windows, macos, audio

I'm looking for an audio processing library that i can use to do some on-the-fly audio editing in my program, such as turn a knob and it'll increase the pitch of the audio file being played, without saving the change to the song file itself. And i plan to make this program for windows and mac so i would need a cross platform library. I don't have much money to spare so it can't cost too much either. My program will be commercially available if that changes anything. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

SoX at http://sox.sourceforge.net/

Wavesurfer at http://www.speech.kth.se/wavesurfer/